What are the rules of Catholic Church on celebration of Holy Mass along with the administration of Sacrament of Matrimony?
Of late, it has become a rule rather than exception to celebrate Holy Mass along with the Sacrament of Matrimony, in many places. It is beneficial on Sundays for the invitees who may come from far off places. But, with back-to-back Services to cater to increased number of the faithful, many churches do not allow marriage on Sundays. That puts additional burden on weekdays on churches which may have to accommodate too many number of weddings combined with Holy Mass, each running into hours.
Moreover, with inter-faith  marriages increasing in frequency, it becomes a matter of worry for the Celebrant to ' convince' non-Catholics (and sometimes Non-Christians) who come forward to receive Holy Communion.
It is also not clear if the Holy Mass can be interluded with the prayers of Sacrament of Matrimony, with the Celebrant digressing from the Missal here and there to insert prayers ' suitable to the special occasion'
My question is : What are the rules of Catholic Church on celebration of Holy Mass along with the administration of Sacrament of Matrimony ?

I attempted to edit, but I guess since you have 13k rep and I have 900 it won't let me. (it claims I should submit edits for formatting etc, which is what I was doing) Can you make that into 2 paragraphs and a separate stand alone sentence with the question at the bottom? :)

Thanks, Wyrsa. Reputation in CSE does not make a User perfect in syntax and layout. I will do as you have suggested. By the way, if a User gets offended by someone else editing the question, he/ she can overrule it by yet another editing .

By the way, your  resume on CSE User's page says that you want to appreciate darkness so as to stay put in light. Good thought. But, please steer clear of the 'Black Holes ' which will not let you see light again !

No worries, I just have a very "Jungian" perspective and it aligns very well with my faith. It is the sin we do not prepare for that catches us at the doorstep to devour us. But yeah, the site really didnt want to let me edit. shrug

You have to earn a specific Badge for that. I am sure, you soon will !
